# Redeploy segments throws error is Sitecore 8

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-dms, sitecore-analytics

I'm trying to redeploy segments for sitecore analytics. We  are using sitecore 8 update 5.

But when I click Redeploy Segments button at /admin/redeploymarketingdata.aspx I get the following error

> Could not create object of type
>   "Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Workflow.DeploySegmentAction,Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client"
>   (method: Sitecore.Pipelines.Processor.Invoke(PipelineArgs args)).

```
Stack Trace: 


[Exception: Could not create object of type "Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Workflow.DeploySegmentAction,Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client" (method: Sitecore.Pipelines.Processor.Invoke(PipelineArgs args)).]
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Error.Raise(String error, String method) +129
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Processor.GetObject() +131
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Processor.Invoke(PipelineArgs args) +66
   Sitecore.Nexus.Pipelines.NexusPipelineApi.Resume(PipelineArgs args, Pipeline pipeline) +398
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.Start(PipelineArgs args, Boolean atomic) +366
   Sitecore.Workflows.Simple.Workflow.ExecuteCommandActionsAndTransition(Item commandItem, Item dataItem, StringDictionary commentFields, Object[] parameters, Processor callback) +550
   Sitecore.Workflows.Simple.Workflow.Execute(String commandID, Item item, String comments, Boolean allowUI, Object[] parameters) +225
   ASP.sitecore_admin_redeploymarketingdata_aspx.DeploySegments() +1841
   ASP.sitecore_admin_redeploymarketingdata_aspx.Redeploy() +341
   ASP.sitecore_admin_redeploymarketingdata_aspx.__RenderpnlResults(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) +50
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +131
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) +15
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +52
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +246
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +394
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +49
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +111
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +246
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +40
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5363
```

I don't find any other analytics error other than this.

Comment: Is your reporting.secondary database is enabled in connection strings config?

Comment: Is this the full error? If there was a stack trace, please include that as well.

Comment: @A.Dylevich no its commented out.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko Here you go, added stack trace.

Comment: @A.Dylevich: Even if I uncomment the secondary database connection string, I get the same error.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. The secondary database should actually be excluded from connection string to perform redeploy marketing data

Comment: No problem, I figured that out @A.Dylevich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Workflow.DeploySegmentAction, Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client` is not a part of Sitecore 8.0 U-5, but it was presented in previous updates. Looks like your Sitecore instance was upgraded up to U-5 from previous one.

The reason of the exception is item (_id: {22762234-2C2B-4008-89FD-FE0623B97622}) in master database. The item should be removed automatically during installation of [Sitecore Update Installation Wizard 1.0.0 rev. 150804.zip](https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/68953F3BA7ED48B9963DAAF3F6213C1A.ashx) package as a step of upgrade.

Check that you followed all steps from [Upgrade Guild](https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/9D70BC5960C9401F8EC603E681088A6C.ashx) during upgrade.

Comment: Thanks Dude, You just saved my day. Just deleted the workflow action at _/sitecore/system/Workflows/Segment/Initializing/Deploy/Deploy Segment_ and now it works fine :)